# Read yaml line number in Jenkins Pipeline

Tags: jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

How to get the line number of yml file in jenkins pipeline.

I am able to get it using groovy

```
def yaml =new  File ('C:/Users/senthiln-1/yaml.yml')
    yaml.text.lines().eachWithIndex { String line, int lineNo ->
        if (line.contains('key1')) {
            println "Found matching $line on line $lineNo"
        }
    }
```

But how the same I can get in Jenkins pipeline

```
node {
  datas = readYaml file: 'release.yml'
}
```

Comment: Why not simply use the Groovy code in the pipeline after replacing the file read with the `readYaml` step?

Comment: Can you elaborate. Sorry I did not get it

Answer (score 0):

Check the following code.

```
def data = readFile file: 'test.yml'
data.split('\n').eachWithIndex { line, i ->
      if (line.contains('key3')) {
        println "Found matching $line on line $i"
    }
    
}
```